# How to create repository mirror for alpine linux?

Tags: bintray

How to create repository mirror for alpine linux? We are not seeing an option for create a repo for apk package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpine is not yet supported by [JFrog Bintray](https://www.jfrog.com/bintray/). Also, Bintray is not intended for mirorring (proxying) other repositories. It is a software distribution service.

On the other hand, [JFrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) does support proxying other repositories, but Alpine is not yet supported... There is already a feature request pending: [Add support for Alpine Linux repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-9985).